# The meaning of "pareil X que Y"

Tags: constructions, comparatifs

> La pierre ne réagit pas **pareil** ici **qu**'à Bhujeba.

{ Bhujeba is the name of a location.}

Does the sentence mean:

> The stone doesn’t react here **either, just like** in Bhujeba.

I’m not fully sure how to use this "pareil X que Y" construction. Is this synonymous with:

> La pierre ne réagit pas ici **pareil à** à Bhujeba.

Comment: Laure's answer is well detailed, so I will just give a possible translation to English: "The stone doesn't react here the same way it does in Bhujeba".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Pareil** est ici un adverbe qui veut dire « de la même façon que ». 
Cet emploi de pareil, très répandu, est signalé comme familier dans *Le bon usage*.

« La pierre ne réagit pas pareil ici qu'à Bhujeba. » veut dire qu'elle ne réagit pas **de la même façon** (**de façon identique**, **de la même manière**) ici et à Bhujeba.

On pourrait aussi employer **comme** mais en faisant aussi très attention à la ponctuation :

« La pierre ne réagit pas ici comme à Bhujeba. » veut dire aussi qu'elle ne  réagit pas de la même façon ici qu'à Bhujeba.

Par contre si on écrit : « La pierre ne réagit pas, ici comme à Bhujeba. »  ça veut dire qu'elle ne réagit ni ici ni à Bhujeba.

La remarque vaut aussi pour « La pierre ne réagit pas, pareil ici qu'à Bhujeba. » la virgule (qui se traduit pas une pause à l'oral) change le sens et la phrase veut dire qu'elle ne réagit ni ici ni à Bhujeba. Merci à @Gilles pour son commentaire.

---

**Pareil** peut aussi être **adjectif** (synonyme de *semblable*) :

- Ta veste est pareille à la mienne.
  À l'oral on entend souvent « pareil que » (pareille que la mienne) mais c'est considéré comme incorrect donc il faut éviter de l'écrire.

---

**Pareil** peut aussi être un nom :

- Il n'a pas son pareil pour raconter des histoires.

Comment: Et aussi « La pierre (ne) réagit pas, pareil ici qu'à Bhujeba », qui est familier, et veut dire « la pierre ne réagit pas, ici comme à Bhujeba ». La virgule change le sens, et à l'oral on entendrait bien une pause entre les deux parties.

Comment: @Laure Est-ce que "pareillement" est plus correct que "pareil" dans la première phrase ? Car il me semble que "pareil" est normalement uniquement un adjectif, ce qui explique que son emploi en tant qu'adverbe soit du registre familier (voire purement erroné et employé uniquement à l'oral).

Comment: @SimonDéchamps Pareil est employé comme adverbe  depuis le 15e siècle, donc bien installé dans la langue. On le trouve aussi très fréquemment à l'écrit. Une recherche sur google books le confirme [voir le ngram](http://bit.ly/2aNP9oa). Pareillement est possible pour remplacer pareil adverbe. personnellement je ne l'emploie jamais, je lui préfère « de même » ou « de la même façon ».

Answer (score 1):

```
La pierre ne réagit pas pareil ici qu'à Bhujeba.
```

A correct translation will be :

```
The stone doesn't react here as it does in Bhujeba.
```

Comment: Bienvenue sur French Language.  Please visit the [Help Centre on how to answer questions.](http://french.stackexchange.com/help) Translations don't explain anything. Welcome to French Language.

Comment: as she used a translation to clarify the meaning, I do the same with a more correct one!!!